# C# string + vs. +=

Tags: c#

Why does `string += char + int` work differently to `string = string + char + int`?

```
char c = '0';
int i = 123;
string s = "";
s += c + i;  // Evaluated as s = s + (c + i);
Console.WriteLine($"s: \"{s}\"");  // s: "171"

s = "";
s = s + c + i;  // Evaluated as s = (s + c) + i;
Console.WriteLine($"s: \"{s}\"");  // s: "0123"
```

Tested on C# 4.0-9.0.

As described in [C# language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#compound-assignment):

> If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible
> to the type of x, the operation is evaluated as x = x op y, ...

PS: this is real-life situation:

```
path += Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + fileId + ".txt";
```

Comment: `+` is evaluated left to right in both cases. It makes total sense to me. And the general rule is, that if you think you found an old bug in C#, you're probably wrong.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong part of that document, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#operator-precedence-and-associativity for precedence rules: assignments, including compound assignments come last, therefore `c + i` in `s += c + i` is right-associative with respect to `s +=` @PalleDue not quite right, assignments are always right associative

Comment: @Charlieface: Of course they are. I was talking about the `+` operator, not the `+=` operator.

Comment: Thank you, @Charlieface, your answer changed my mind. Also I understand that evaluation rule should not be perceived in naive way, but as "`x += y` evaluated as `x = x + (y)`". I think people who invented the precedence rules have in mind such example: `x -= y - z` that should not be evaluated as `x = (x - y) - z`, but `x = x - (y - z)`.

Answer (score 2):

`int` and `char` can be cast to each other in c#. `char` can be added to an int to produce an int, because ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) - emphasis added)

> The `char` type supports comparison, equality, increment, and decrement operators. Moreover, for char operands, **arithmetic and bitwise logical operators perform an operation on the corresponding character codes and produce the result of the int type**.

For example:

```cs
'0' + 123 
// result: 171
```

And an int can be converted back into a char:

```cs
(char)48
// result: '0'
```

So when you try to concatenate with `+=`, the `int` and `char` are evaluated to an `int` type since there is nothing telling them to do otherwise. Prepend with a string, however:

```cs
string s += "" + c + i;
// result: "0123"
```

Now the compiler, reading your expression from left to right, implicitly calls `ToString` on `c` and `i`, so no arithmetic operations occur, only string concatenation (That's why `string s = s + c + i` behaved differently).

#### Update

Per your comment:

> Now I can reformulate my question:) Why `s += c + i` is equivalent to `s += (c + i)` instead of `(s += c) + i`

Everything after the `+=` is evaluated **before** the concatenation (see [Operator precedence and associativity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#operator-precedence-and-associativity)). Think of everything right of the `=` as its own variable. Essentialy:

```cs
var right = c + i;
var left = s;
s = left + right; // effectively same as s += c + i;

// or

s = s + (c + i /** everything on the right side in order here **/);
```

Comment: Now I can reformulate my question:)
Why `s += c + i` is equivalent to `s += (c + i)` instead of `(s += c) + i`

Comment: And the answer is: because `binary +` has higher precedence than `+=`. It is confusing a little, but it should be known by profies.